# How is logistic regression parallelized in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I wouldlike to have some insight about the method used to parallelize the logistic regression in the ML library, I already tried to check the source code but I didn't understand the process.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide any relevant code you have used so far so we can assist you further. Please see this link for more information on asking a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark uses a so called mini batch gradient descent for regression:

http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#minibatchgradientdescent

In a nutshell, it works like this:

1. Select a sample of the data
2. Compute the gradient on each row of the sample
3. Aggregate the gradient
4. Back to step 1

The actual optimisation code for Spark is from this line:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/GradientDescent.scala#L234

Comment: Oh ok, so this is the gradient computing part which is parallelized. Thank you !